# In JavaScript, does an empty regex pattern have defined behavior?

Tags: javascript, regex

```
var pattern = /(?:)/
```

From my testing, it seems to match everything. Is this the defined behavior?

Comment: @mini: That isn't true.  The reverse question has come up and gotten lots of attention.

Comment: I could imagine a system where the user is expected to supply a regex string for matching "something" and his code encapsulates that regex into a `(?:...)`, and then evals it. In fact somebody asked about this case not long ago; they were letting people supply regexes at runtime.

Comment: @SLaks: What's the reverse question?

Comment: A regex that matches nothing.  I'm trying to find it.

Comment: @SLaks: You mean `/^$/`?

Comment: A regex that matches nothing? Like, `/^$/`? Aren't there better ways to do that (e.g. comparing to empty string)

Comment: @mini: Almost.  He didn't want to match _anything_.  (I answered `/$.^/`) The question was deleted, though.  @Zirak: He wanted it for a validation framework, I think.

Comment: @SLaks: Even so, that's a different question. I figured this one is just... unproductive.

Comment: Does an OP have to justify the reason behind every question they ask?

Comment: Both `/.^/` and `/$./` mismatch any string.  Note that `/$^/` still matches the empty string because the beginning is also the ending.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This doesn't directly answer the question, but here's what the spec has to say about the empty regular expression:

From [**15.5.4.14 String.prototype.split (separator, limit)**](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_15.5.4.14)

> The value of separator may be an empty String, **an empty regular expression**, or a regular expression that can match an empty String.

And from [**7.8.5   Regular Expression Literals**](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_7.8.5)

> NOTE     Regular expression literals may not be empty; instead of representing an empty regular expression literal, the characters // start a single-line comment. To specify an empty regular expression, use: `/(?:)/` .

So given that it is an accepted value for the separator in `.split()`, I would guess that it is the defined behavior as a way to split on every character.

```
"fjeij;als#%^&é.\n isoij\t;oi`1=+-]\r".split(/(?:)/);

["f", "j", "e", "i", "j", ";", "a", "l", "s", "#", "%", "^", "&", "é", ".", "
", " ", "i", "s", "o", "i", "j", "  ", ";", "o", "i", "`", "1", "=", "+", "-", "]", "
"]
```

Comment: Thank you! This seems reasonably defined, because it would be odd for patterns to match different strings in different contexts.

Comment: Try in console `new RegExp()` :))

Answer (score 9):

`/(?:)/` matches "nothing", which matches everything. There is nothing in everything.  Heh heh.
Yes, I would expect this.