# Regular Expressions- Match Anything

Tags: regex

How do I make an expression to match absolutely anything (including whitespaces)? 
Example:

**Regex:**   I bought _____ sheep.

**Matches:** I bought sheep. I bought a sheep. I bought five sheep.

I tried using `(.*)`, but that doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: `.*` should work. Can you paste your actual code?

Comment: What language are you coding in?

Comment: a dot won't match a newline

Comment: It's not working because there is two spaces between "bought" and "sheep". so `I bought sheep` is wrong and `I bought  sheep` is correct.

Comment: `(?s:.)` - the [inline modifier group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html) match any char including line break chars. In your case, it would be something like this: `(?s:.*?)`. Taken from the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33312193/15164646) by [Wiktor Stribiżew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%c5%bcew).

Comment: Just `(.* )?` works for me. This [regex](https://tools.waytolearnx.com/regex-tester/e8052cc15a10) should do the job.

Answer (score 453):

Normally the dot matches any character *except newlines*.

So if `.*` isn't working, set the "dot matches newlines, too" option (or use `(?s).*`).

If you're using JavaScript, which doesn't have a "dotall" option, try `[\s\S]*`. This means "match any number of characters that are either whitespace or non-whitespace" - effectively "match any string".

Another option that only works for JavaScript (and is not recognized by any other regex flavor) is `[^]*` which also matches any string. But `[\s\S]*` seems to be more widely used, perhaps because it's more portable.

Comment: `.*` doesn't match `\n` but it maches a string that contains only `\n` because it matches 0 character.

Comment: if using  Javascript don't forget to slash the slash when setting a variable to this pattern eg: var pattern = "[\\s\\S]*";

Comment: the `(?s).*` works for me matched everything including new line

Comment: There is a PROBLEM with using /[\s\S]*/ .  If you  use it in your code and then comment out such code that causes a syntax error because  the end of the pattern is taken to mean the end of the comment.  You then need to remove that pattern from the commented-out code to make it work. But then if you ever un-comment it again it will not work any more, or not work like it used to,  and should.

Comment: This would be the case with any regex ending in an asterisk. Of course it's easy to avoid by either adding something after `*` (as in `/.*(?:)/`) or using the regex constructor (`var foo = new RegExp(".*")`).

Comment: I pretty much never want to match 0 of something, so I just use [\s\S]+ instead.

Comment: In 2018, the [dotall flag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/dotAll) was added to the specification. Here we are approaching 2020 and Firefox still hasn't implemented it. Give them some [heat](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1361856).

Comment: Also, it looks like JavaScript actually has dotall now https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/dotAll ? So you could also just

Comment: @Tim Pietzcker good one! ((?s).*) works perfectly!!! Thanks!

Comment: @AstraBear In JS `pattern = "[\\s\\S]*";` you don't need to slash the slash, check this [demo](https://tools.waytolearnx.com/regex-tester/88da73f928ec).

Answer (score 255):

`(.*?)` matches anything - I've been using it for years.

Comment: but does that match a newline?

Comment: I used this on Sublime Text and it worked perfectly. Thanks!
`("title":".*?")`

Comment: In Javascript, use `[\s\S]*` or `[^]*`.

Comment: I don't know but every time I use this expression, I feel guilty, for not making a specific expression for my use case. If say, `w+` isn't enough, I end up using `.+`. Luckily hasn't come back to bite me yet.

Comment: Works for me using Python

Comment: This doesn't seem to include new lines or trailing full stops. I found this slight alteration hits everything 
 (?s).*

Comment: That matches 0 or more of anything included in the "."

Comment: This definitely doesn't work in Python - in fact, it will do the exact opposite. The `?` makes the expression non-greedy, so it will match *nothing*. Thus: `re.search('(.*)', 'abc').group(1)` -> `'abc'` and `re.search('(.*?)', 'abc').group(1)` -> `''`. In Python, the correct syntax is `(?s)(.*)` (or `re.S` / `re.DOTALL` can be passed in the `flags` argument).

Answer (score 130):

**Choose & memorize 1 of the following!!! :)**

```
[\s\S]*
[\w\W]*
[\d\D]*
```

**Explanation:**

`\s`: whitespace `\S`: not whitespace

`\w`: word `\W`: not word

`\d`: digit `\D`: not digit

(You can exchange the `*` for `+` if you want 1 or MORE characters [instead of 0 or more]).

**BONUS EDIT:**

If you want to match everything on a single line, you can use this:

```
[^\n]+
```

**Explanation:**

`^`: not

`\n`: linebreak

`+`: for 1 character or more

Answer (score 31):

Try this:

```
I bought (.* )?sheep
```

or even

```
I bought .*sheep
```

Comment: but this doesn't match new line, check this [demo](https://tools.waytolearnx.com/regex-tester/47ebfb01c087).

Answer (score 31):

`/.*/` works great if there are no line breaks. If it has to match line breaks, here are some solutions:

| Solution | Description |
| --- | --- |
| `/.*/s` | `/s` (dot all flag) makes `.` (wildcard character) match anything, including line breaks. Throw in an `*` (asterisk), and it will match everything. [Read more](https://regexr.com/589nh). |
| `/[\s\S]*/` | `\s` (whitespace metacharacter) will match any whitespace character (space; tab; line break; ...), and `\S` (opposite of `\s`) will match anything that is **not** a whitespace character. `*` (asterisk) will match all occurrences of the character set (Encapsulated by `[]`). [Read more](https://regexr.com/589ne). |

Comment: does it match no chars? Want match one or more.

Comment: Yes, the solutions I posted above will also match nothing/empty string. If you want to match at least one character, simply replace `*` with `+`.

Comment: `/[\s\S]*/` works to me to match anything ignore break lines

Comment: You have saved me almost another 48 hours of search

Answer (score 12):

Because `.` Find a single character, except newline or line terminator.

So, to match anything, You can use like this: `(.|\n)*?`

Hope it helps!

Comment: Maybe I am a bit ignorant, but to my knowledge the `?` makes the preceding quantifier lazy, causing it to match as few characters as possible (in the case, zero!)

Comment: Also, this will only work with LF (`\n`) line endings, but not CR (`\r`) or CRLF (`\r\n`) line endings.

Comment: nope, not in dart it doesn't

Answer (score 7):

Use `.*`, and make sure you are using your implementations' equivalent of single-line so you will match on **line endings**.

There is a great explanation here -> http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html

Comment: in dart it doesn't

Comment: Good point @MwBakker. If you could lend me your time machine, I’ll travel back to July 11, 2011 and tell myself to wait a few months for Dart to be released.

Answer (score 7):

If you're using JavaScript, ES2018 added the `/s` (dotAll) flag. With the `/s` flag, the dot `.` will match any character, including a newline.

```js
console.log("line_1\nline_2".match(/.+/s))
```

**Note**: It's not supported by all browsers yet.

Answer (score 3):

`(.*?)` does not work for me. I am trying to match comments surrounded by `/* */`, which may contain multiple lines.

Try this:

```
([a]|[^a])
```

This regex matches `a` or `anything else expect a`. Absolutely, it means matching everything.

BTW, in my situation, `/\*([a]|[^a])*/` matches C style comments.

Thank @mpen for a more concise way.

```
[\s\S]
```

Comment: The most common way to do this in JS is `[\s\S]` -- i.e. match spaces and non-spaces.

Answer (score 3):

For JavaScript the best and simplest answer would seem to be `/.\*/`.

As suggested by others `/(.*?)/` would work as well but `/.\*/` is simpler. The `()` inside the pattern are not needed, as far as I can see nor the ending `?` to match absolutely anything (including empty strings)

---

**NON-SOLUTIONS:**

- `/[\s\S]/` does NOT match empty strings so it's not the solution.
- `/[\s\S]\*/` DOES match also empty strings. But it has a problem: If you use it in your code then you can't comment out such code because the `*/` is interpreted as end-of-comment.

`/([\s\S]\*)/` works and does not have the comment-problem. But it is longer and more complicated to understand than `/.*/`.

Comment: BTW. it seems the code-excerpts above make Stack Overflow render parts of my answer in italics, that was not my intention.

Answer (score 3):

The 2018 specification provides the [s flag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Parameters) (alias: dotAll), so that `.` will match any character, including linebreaks:

```js
const regExAll = /.*/s; //notice the 's'

let str = `
Everything
    in  this
            string
                    will
                        be
    matched. Including whitespace (even Linebreaks).
`;

console.log(`Match:`, regExAll.test(str)); //true
console.log(`Index Location:`, str.search(regExAll));

let newStr = str.replace(regExAll,"");
console.log(`Replaced with:`,newStr); //Index: 0
```

Answer (score 3):

1. Regex:

   ```
   /I bought.*sheep./
   ```

   Matches - the **whole** string till the end of line

   `I bought sheep. I bought a sheep. I bought five sheep.`
2. Regex:

   ```
   /I bought(.*)sheep./
   ```

   Matches - the **whole** string and also capture the **sub string** within () for further use

   `I bought sheep. I bought a sheep. I bought five sheep.`

   I bought`sheep. I bought a sheep. I bought five`sheep.

   Example using **Javascript/Regex**

   ```
   'I bought sheep. I bought a sheep. I bought five sheep.'.match(/I bought(.*)sheep./)[0];
   ```

   Output:

   "I bought sheep. I bought a sheep. I bought five sheep."

   ```
   'I bought sheep. I bought a sheep. I bought five sheep.'.match(/I bought(.*)sheep./)[1];
   ```

   Output:

   " sheep. I bought a sheep. I bought five "

Answer (score 1):

One option is the **empty regular expression**, denoted in JavaScript as `/(?:)/`. (You can also use `new RegExp()`). Logically, an empty regular expression should match strings containing "emptiness" at any position--which of course is all of them.

See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6091974/in-javascript-does-an-empty-regex-pattern-have-defined-behavior) and [this blog post](https://2ality.com/2012/09/empty-regexp.html) for discussion and more details.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$str = "I bought _ sheep";
preg_match("/I bought (.*?) sheep", $str, $match);
print_r($match);
?>
```

http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/b2243.php

Answer (score 0):

I recommend use `/(?=.*...)/g`

**Example**

```
const text1 = 'I am using regex';
/(?=.*regex)/g.test(text1) // true

const text2 = 'regex is awesome';
/(?=.*regex)/g.test(text2) // true

const text3 = 'regex is util';
/(?=.*util)(?=.*regex)/g.test(text3) // true

const text4 = 'util is necessary';
/(?=.*util)(?=.*regex)/g.test(text4) // false because need regex in text
```

Use [regex101](https://regex101.com/)  to test

Answer (score 0):

Honestly alot of the answers are old so i found that if you simply just test any string regardless of character content with "/.*/i" will sufficiently get EVERYTHING.

Comment: `/.*/i` will not match line breaks. Further, `/i` (the ‘ignore case’ flag) is redundant. 

Answer (score -3):

I use this: (.|\n)+ works like a charm for me!

Comment: **Never** use this pattern (unless you have to in ElasticSearch regex flavor). It causes huge amount of backtrackings steps, and leads to stack overflow issues. Besides, this solution is mentioned [earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56105382/3832970).