# Regex to match anything

Tags: regex

I know it seems a bit redundant but I'd like a regex to match anything.

At the moment we are using `^*$` but it doesn't seem to match no matter what the text.

I do a manual check for no text but the test view we use is always validated with a regex. However, sometimes we need it to validate anything using a regex. i.e. it doesn't matter what is in the text field, it can be anything.

I don't actually produce the regex and I'm a complete beginner with them.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regular Expressions- Match Anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6711971/regular-expressions-match-anything)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The regex `.*` will match anything (including the empty string, as Junuxx points out).

Comment: And nothing, which it seems he doesn't want. So, `.+`

Comment: Checking for nothing doesn't matter too much as I'm doing that outside of the regex. I will try both though, thanks.

Comment: This regex does not match "\n".

Answer (score 37):

The chosen answer is slightly incorrect, as it wont match line breaks or returns. This [regex to match anything](http://regexr.com/3f4vo) is useful if your desired selection includes any line breaks:

`[\s\S]+`

`[\s\S]` matches a character that is either a whitespace character (including line break characters), or a character that is not a whitespace character. Since all characters are either whitespace or non-whitespace, this character class matches any character. the `+` matches one or more of the preceding expression

Comment: A slightly more concise alternative: `[^]+`

Comment: [^]+ is only valid in the JavaScript regex engine. It will not work with Python, PCRE, Go, etc

Comment: `[\s\S]+` is working. `.*` doesn't work in javascript.

Answer (score 9):

`^` is the beginning-of-line *anchor*, so it will be a "zero-width match," meaning it won't match any actual characters (and the first character matched after the `^` will be the first character of the string). Similarly, `$` is the end-of-line anchor.

`*` is a *quantifier*. It will not *by itself* match anything; it only indicates *how many times* a portion of the pattern can be matched. Specifically, it indicates that the previous "atom" (that is, the previous character or the previous parenthesized sub-pattern) can match *any number* of times.

To actually match some set of characters, you need to use a *character class*. As RichieHindle pointed out, the character class you need here is `.`, which represents any character except newlines (and it can be made to match newlines as well using the appropriate flag). So `.*` represents `*` (any number) matches on `.` (any character). Similarly, `.+` represents `+` (at least one) matches on `.` (any character).

Comment: A mysterious downvote appears! Is my answer factually incorrect? TL;DR? Not quite an answer to the question as posed? *We'll never know for sure!*

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a bit old post, but we can have different ways like :

1. .*
2. (.*?)