# empty regex matches any string

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I was trying to find a regex that matches any string! and after some search I found almost all the answers says that `[\s\S]` will match any string as said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4026213/php-regex-any-character) or `.*` as said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15496156/regex-to-match-anything)

But while playing a bit with PHP [`preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) I found that an empty regex is matching any string!

```
if(preg_match("//u", "")) echo "empty string matchs\n";
else echo "empty string does not match\n";

if(preg_match("//u", "abc")) echo "abc matchs\n";
else echo "abc does not match\n";

if(preg_match("//u", "\n")) echo "new line matchs\n";
else echo "new line does not match\n";

if(preg_match("//u", "/")) echo "/ matchs\n";
else echo "/ does not match\n";

exit;
```

this will output

```
empty string matchs
abc matchs
new line matchs
/ matchs
```

live demo (https://eval.in/845001)

**Can I use this empty regex safely to match anything ? and what does an empty regex mean ?**

*If you are asking why would I need a regex that matches anything, that is because I'm using a function that requires a regex parameter as part of it's string validation functionality and I want it to accept anything.*

Comment: The regex to match no string is no regex. just do `if($string == "")` or `if (strlen($string)== 0)`

Comment: @Ibu Thanks. But I must pass any regex to the function that will validate the string.

Comment: Your first condition should be to check if the string is empty first, then you go into the regexes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An empty regex pattern `//` matches at start, end and any position between characters in a string. See this demo at eval.in [`preg_match_all('//', "foo", $out);`](https://eval.in/845209) which returns 4 empty matches:

> `Array[0] => [1] => [2] => [3] => )`

As `preg_match` would just check for the first match it should be fine to use the empty pattern. However generally I'd probably prefer `/^/` which matches *start of the string* that every string has.

`[\s\S]` ([shorts](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) for whitespaces together with non-whitespaces in a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)) means *just any character* and is usually used [line-break related](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-interesting-character-classes.html#line_break) to also match newlines where there is no flag available for making [the dot](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html) match linebreaks. Often used with [JS regex which does not support `s` flag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1068308/5527985). Similar are `[\D\d]` (digits and non-digits), `[\w\W]` (word characters and non word characters). Also possible with JS regex is `[^]` a negated empty character class for "not nothing".

To use `/[\s\S]/` or one of the others without quantifier will require at least one character.

Further to mention that in your patterns you use the `u` flag for unicode regex. There is probably no reason to use this flag together with an empty pattern or just checking for start of the string. Interesting with pcre [unicode regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html) might be the following escape sequences.

- `\X` matches an unicode grapheme. Similar the dot in `u`-mode (but not newlines).
- `\C` matches one data unit ([similar using the dot without `u` flag](https://eval.in/845224) on unicode input).

Well, I don't really see why one would need a pattern to match any string, but wrote for interest :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are correct. Another alternative is `/.?/`. There are many possibilities to accept all strings.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time. So this empty regex can be used safely to match any string? and what does it mean ? Isn't it suppose to mean , match **empty string!** ?