# Convert text url link into clickable link

Tags: javascript, regex

Convert all occurrence of `www` in string with `http://www` I have tried

Regular expression: `/^www(?!http\:\/\/|https\:\/\/)./g;` but it's working only in case when any character or digit don't precede www. For example: `Find me at www.test.com` in this case it's failing but it's working for `www.google.com find me on this`. I don't know how to put condition in regular exp for this.

```
function mailify(text)
{
  var regEx = /^www(?!http\:\/\/|https\:\/\/)/g;
  return text.replace(regEx, "http://www");
}

console.log(mailify("www.ni@gmail.com"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
return text.replace("www", "http://www");
```

Comment: Hey ur reg ex is not working check with this : console.log(mailify("fine ksajd kajsl d www.ni@gmail.com")); it is replacing http://www.ni@gmail.com while it should be fine ksajd kajsl d http://www.ni@gmail.com

Comment: Misread, I thought it was extracting. But if it's just text-to-text replacement you can use two strings.

Comment: Thanks! It was more of doodling then a project. Just wondering, does my new answer solve the problem?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46482/discussion-between-nishant-and-spencer-wieczorek)

Answer (score 0):

Nishant this is helpful:

```
  function mailify(text)
    {
      var regEx = /www/g;
      return text.replace(regEx, "http://www");
    }

    console.log(mailify("www.google.com find me on this"));
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because your regular expression begins with a `^` which means your expression has to start with www. Try that:

```
/^.*www(?!http\:\/\/|https\:\/\/)./g;
```

Source : [Regular Expressions- Match Anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6711971/regular-expressions-match-anything).

Answer (score 0):

Place the lookahead before the www:

```
var regEx = /^(?!https?:\/\/)www/;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below regex :

```
/([^/]|^)(www)/g
```

Code :

```
var reg=/([^/]|^)(www)/g
var line="something www.some.com , http://some1.com"
console.log(line.replace(reg,"$1http://$2"))
```

OUTPUT:

```
 "something http://www.some.com , http://some1.com"
```

**[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/gV7yT3)**

**Explanation :**

[image]

Comment: your reg ex is failing for console.log(mailify("fine ksajd kajsl d http://www.ni@gmail.com")); Here output is comming: fine ksajd kajsl d http://http://www.ni@gmail.com

Comment: Your code is failing : "niasodjhttp://www niosjado   sdjfklsjdl f www.test.com www.machine,com"

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
    function mailify(text)
    {
      var regEx = /\b(https?:\/\/)?www\./g;
      return text.replace(regEx, 'http://www.');
    }

    console.log(mailify('www.yourlink.com notalinkwww.yourlink.com http://www.yourlink.comm'));
```

You also need to check there is a dot after 'www' to make sure that it marks the start of a link.

If you just want the links to be CLICKABLE, you have to do this:

```
function mailify(text)
{
  var regEx = /\b((https?:\/\/)?www\.\S*)/g;
  return text.replace(regEx, '<a href="$1">$1</a>');
}
```

Comment: Your reg ex is failing for : gmailify("fine ksajd kajsl d sadasdsadwww.googl.com ")

Comment: Also for : "fine ksajd kajsl d sadasdsad www.googl.com dfgdfg"

Comment: sadasdsadwww.googl.com is not a link, if you want this matched, remove the \b at the beginning. Also, try gmailify('YourString') not gmailify("YourString")

Answer (score 0):

Replace any text having `http://` or `https` or `ftp`or `file` or only `www` or `http://www` or `https://www`and followed by any character digit and special character  and even back spaces into click able link.

**Reg Ex:** 
`/(\b((https?|ftp|file):\/\/|(www))[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]*)/ig`

```
function UriphiMe(text) {
      var exp = /(\b((https?|ftp|file):\/\/|(www))[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]*)/ig; 
      return text.replace(exp,"<a href='$1'>$1</a>");
}
```

**I have tested by below string:**

1. Find me on to www.google.com
2. www
3. Find me on to www.http://www.com
4. Follow me on : http://www.nishantwork.wordpress.com
5. http://www.nishantwork.wordpress.com
6. Follow me on : http://www.nishantwork.wordpress.com
7. https://stackoverflow.com/users/430803/nishant

Note: If you don't want to pass `www` as valid one just use below reg ex: 
`/(\b((https?|ftp|file):\/\/|(www))[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig`

Reference: [How to replace plain URLs with links?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37684/how-to-replace-plain-urls-with-links)

Please add as a comment if reg ex is failing and please let me know if I am wrong.