# matching any character including newlines in a Python regex subexpression, not globally

Tags: python, regex

I want to use [`re.MULTILINE`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MULTILINE) but **NOT** [`re.DOTALL`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.DOTALL), so that I can have a regex that includes both an "any character" wildcard and the normal `.` wildcard that doesn't match newlines.

Is there a way to do this? What should I use to match any character in those instances that I want to include newlines?

Comment: just do something like `[\s\S]` or `[\w\W]`

Comment: `[^\r\n]` == anything but CR/LF

Comment: Hi Jason, unless I'm missing something, "python" + "regex" can be implied from the tags, so does not need to be specified in the title (per the "no tags in titles" guideline)?

Comment: because SO's list of related questions DOES NOT INCLUDE THE TAGS so context information is important.

Comment: The "no tags in titles" either needs to be a guideline (not a requirement) or needs to be revisited, or SO needs to start showing tags in the list of related questions.

Answer (score 147, accepted):

To match a newline, or "any symbol" without `re.S`/`re.DOTALL`, you may use any of the following:

1. `(?s).` - the [inline modifier group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html) with `s` flag on sets a scope where all `.` patterns match any char including line break chars
2. Any of the following work-arounds:

```
[\s\S]
[\w\W]
[\d\D]
```

The main idea is that the opposite shorthand classes inside a character class match any symbol there is in the input string.

Comparing it to `(.|\s)` and other variations with alternation, the character class solution is much more efficient as it involves much less backtracking (when used with a `*` or `+` quantifier). Compare the small example: it takes [`(?:.|\n)+`](https://regex101.com/r/pX7lM6/1) 45 steps to complete, and it takes [`[\s\S]+`](https://regex101.com/r/pX7lM6/2) just 2 steps.

See a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/GZEQNf) where I am matching a line starting with `123` and up to the first occurrence of `3` at the start of a line and including the rest of that line:

```py
import re
text = """abc
123
def
356
more text..."""
print( re.findall(r"^123(?s:.*?)^3.*", text, re.M) )
# => ['123\ndef\n356']
print( re.findall(r"^123[\w\W]*?^3.*", text, re.M) )
# => ['123\ndef\n356']
```

Comment: awesome, thanks! I knew there was a way to do it but couldn't remember.

Comment: Fixed some typos. Sorry for them.

Comment: @IoannisFilippidis You are suggesting using a regex option to match any char. This is out of the current post scope as OP know about the regex options, both `re.M` and `re.S`/`re.DOTALL`, but wants to know how to do it without the flags. Besides, `re.MULTILINE` is a wrong flag to match any char in Python `re` since it only modifies the behavior of `^` and `$` anchors, while `re.S` or `re.DOTALL` make `.` match any char including a newline.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew a link to this answer on your profile for the text "NEVER USE `(.|\n)`!!!" would be useful for regex amateurs like myself.

Answer (score 11):

### Match any character (including new line):

Regular Expression: (Note the use of space ' ' is also there)

```
[\S\n\t\v ]
```

### Example:

```
import re

text = 'abc def ###A quick brown fox.\nIt jumps over the lazy dog### ghi jkl'
# We want to extract "A quick brown fox.\nIt jumps over the lazy dog"
matches = re.findall('###[\S\n ]+###', text)
print(matches[0])
```

**The 'matches[0]' will contain:**
'A quick brown fox.**\n**It jumps over the lazy dog'

### Description of '\S' Python docs:

`\S`
Matches any character which is not a whitespace character.

( See: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax )

Comment: This does not match `\t` or `\v`.

Comment: The `\v` is not ocasionally used but I included it anyway. And the question says to match "any character including newline". So whatever works for him :-) @ApproachingDarknessFish