# Python returns no matches on working regex

Tags: python, regex

I have a string (not raw) in python similar to the following:

```
Plenary Papers (1)
Peer-reviewed Papers (113)
PLENARY MANUSCRIPTS (1)
First Author Index

Harrer
Plenary Papers

One Some title
John W. Doe
2018 Physics SOmething Proceedings
Full Text: Download PDF - PER-Central Record
Show Abstract - Show Citation
PEER REVIEWED MANUSCRIPTS (113)
First Author Index

Doe · Doe2 · Doe3 · Jonathan
Peer-reviewed Papers

Two some title
Alex White, Paul Klee, and Jacson Pollock
2018 Physics Research Conference Proceedings, doi:10.1234/perc.2018.pr.White
Full Text: Download PDF - PER-Central Record
Show Abstract - Show Citation

Tree Some title
Suzanne Heck, Alex Someone, John I. Smith, and Andrew Bourgogne
2018 Physics Education Research Conference Proceedings, doi:10.2345/perc.2018.pr.Heck
Full Text: Download PDF - PER-Central Record
Show Abstract - Show Citation

..
```

I want to scrape the metadata of those three papers, i.e. those few lines after each title (e.g. "One Some title" "John W. Doe", and 2018 Physics Something Proceedings").

I though of using two patterns for the beginning and end of the selection:

'r"\n\n"' and 'r"Show Abstract - Show Citation"'.

This (almost) works on [https://regex101.com/](https://regex101.com/r/iN6pX6/193)using this regular expression:

```
\n\n(.*?)Show Abstract - Show Citation
```

A minor issue is that it is greedy on the first two papers.

but not in python:

```py
    pattern=r"\n\n(.*?)Show Abstract - Show Citation"

    re.findall(pattern, titles) #titles is the text above

    #output is []
    pattern_only_one_line=r"\nShow Abstract - Show Citation"

    re.findall(pattern_only_one_line, titles)

    #output shows three lines
```

Could this be another problem with raw strings?

Comment: Your regex finds no matches - https://regex101.com/r/X9AUw9/1

Comment: it does not match: https://regex101.com/r/37ikGZ/1

Comment: probably a problem with the link. https://regex101.com/r/iN6pX6/193 works?

Comment: Your regex is using the flag single line (dot matches newline) so you will need to do `re.findall(pattern, titles, re.DOTALL)`

Comment: @Wolph yes it is working! Now I am trying to figure out how to use it in .finditer  . you can add an answer if you want

Comment: Duplicate of [How do I match any character across multiple lines in a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159118) then

Comment: Also, [matching any character including newlines in a Python regex subexpression, not globally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33312175/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `re.DOTALL` flag is missing. Without it `.` won't match newlines.

But we can do better (depending on what you need exactly of course): https://regex101.com/r/iN6pX6/199

```py
import re
import pprint

titles = '''
[Omitted for brevity]
..
'''

pattern = r'''
(?P<title>[^\n]+)\n
(?P<subtitle>[^\n]+)\n
((?P<etc>[^\n].*?)\n\n|\n)
'''

# Make sure we don't have any extraneous whitespace but add the separator
titles = titles.strip() + '\n\n'

for match in re.finditer(pattern, titles, re.DOTALL | re.VERBOSE):
    title = match.group('title')
    subtitle = match.group('subtitle')
    etc = match.group('etc')
    print('## %r' % title)
    print('# %r' % subtitle)
    if etc:
      print(etc)
    print()
    # pprint.pprint(match.groupdict())
```

Comment: I am still struggling with finditer. Using the simple pattern I can't get results. With your pattern (I like the idea) I only get the third paper right.

Comment: I noticed I still had your pattern in my code block, that's probably what killed it. Try the new version. You can see the results here: https://repl.it/repls/GentleGoldenBlocks

Comment: Almost there: notice that the second paper is not right: the title is 'Doe · Doe2 · Doe3 · Jonathan' instead of 'Two some title' because the algorithm is greedy. Any idea how to fix this? I tried poking around with '.*?' but still not working

Comment: Sorry for the slow response. The problem is that it always requires the `etc` part. That seems optional so we’ll have to make it optional, take a look at the update :)

Comment: Thanks, the updated code is not solving the problem I mentioned above but I accept your answer. I was able to extract what I need using re.finditer(..., re.DOTALL) as previously suggested

Comment: @aless80 now I get it. That means the "Show Abstract..." part is optional too. I've made a new version: https://repl.it/repls/ExternalBigheartedHertz