# Regex search fail when input has line breaks

Tags: python, regex, python-re

The following regular expression is not returning any match:

```py
import re

regex = '.*match.*fail.*'
pattern = re.compile(regex)
text = '\ntestmatch\ntestfail'

match = pattern.search(text)
```

I managed to solve the problem by changing `text` to `repr(text)` or setting text as a raw string with `r'\ntestmatch\ntestfail'`, but I'm not sure if these are the best approaches. What is the best way to solve this problem?

Comment: Adding on to this, `.` traditionally matches all characters excluding the newline. Thus, even if you escape your string, you still need to consider this.

Comment: Not a good duplicate but this is a common FAQ; hang on while I look for a better one.

Answer (score 4):

Using `repr` or raw string on a target string is a bad idea!
By doing that newline characters are treated as literal '`\n`'.
This is likely to cause unexpected behavior on other test cases.

The real problem is that `.` matches any character **EXCEPT** newline.
If you want to match everything, replace `.` with `[\s\S]`.
This means "whitespace or not whitespace" = "anything".
Using other character groups like `[\w\W]` also works,
[and it is more efficient for adding exception just for newline.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33312193/11556864)

One more thing, it is a good practice to use raw string in **pattern** string(not match target).
This will eliminate the need to escape every characters that has special meaning in normal python strings.

Answer (score 0):

You could add it as an or, but make sure you `\` in the regex string, so regex actually gets the `\n` and not a actual newline.

Something like this:

```
regex = '.*match(.|\\n)*fail.*'
```

This would match anything from the last `\n` to `match`, then any mix or number of `\n` until `testfail`. You can change this how you want, but the idea is the same. Put what you want into a grouping, and then use `|` as an `or`.

[image]

On the left is what this regex pattern matched from your example.