# Match anything after certain character

Tags: javascript, regex

How do I replace anything that goes after certain character? For example:

```
var temp = 'abcdefghikj';
```

and I want to replace all characters with nothing after `c`:

```
temp.replace('c*', '');
```

I looked at this topic but none of the suggested solutions worked for me:
  [Regular Expressions- Match Anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6711971/regular-expressions-match-anything)

Comment: `temp = temp.substring(0, temp.indexOf("c") + 1);`

Comment: I don't know what I'm doing wrong but the expression `\?(.*)` isn't working for me. In my case I need to edit it to `\c(.*)` or perhaps to `\c.*` but it isn't working when used in `temp.replace('\c.*', '');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you wrote is right. You're there:

```js
var temp = 'abcdefghikj';
temp = temp.replace(/c(.*)$/ig, "c");
console.log(temp);
```

Make sure you also need save the return to the original value.

You don't need to use `RegEx` for this simple one. You can simply find the first index of `c` and slice it:

```js
var temp = 'abcdefghikj';
temp = temp.substr(0, temp.indexOf("c") + 1);
console.log(temp);
```