# Creating a blank regex adds a random non-capturing group in Chrome

Tags: javascript, regex, google-chrome

I realized that I couldn't match an empty regex with `/(regex here)/` syntax, because `//` is a comment.

```
'this is a test'.match(//)
> SyntaxError: Unexpected token }
```

So, I tried `new RegExp('')` and it worked:

```
'this is a test'.match(new RegExp(''))
> [""]
```

But when I checked the output of `new RegExp('')`, it was this:

```
new RegExp('')
> /(?:)/
```

Why is this? (I am using Chrome version `26.0.1410.64 (Official Build 193017) m` and this is in the JavaScript console)

Comment: This is specified in the ECMA standard http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.8.5. _"Regular expression literals may not be empty; instead of representing an empty regular expression literal, the characters // start a single-line comment. To specify an empty regular expression, use: /(?:)/."_

Comment: @elclanrs Exactly, you should add that as an answer.

Comment: Also, in [15.10.4.1](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.10.4.1) (which is about the RegExp constructor) the spec states: *If P is the empty String, this specification can be met by letting S be "(?:)".*

Comment: @bfavaretto: I'll post all of this as answer. I missed section 15.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is specified in the ECMA standard in section [7.8.5](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.8.5):

> Regular expression literals may not be empty; instead of representing
>   an empty regular expression literal, the characters // start a
>   single-line comment. To specify an empty regular expression, use:
>   /(?:)/.

Also, in [15.10.4.1](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.10.4.1) the spec states:

> If P is the empty String, this specification can be met by letting S
>   be "(?:)".

Comment: Found a dup that looks exactly the same, LOL. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6091974/in-javascript-does-an-empty-regex-pattern-have-defined-behavior